# ToggleButton not working anymore

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple ToggleButton in one of the tabs of a workbook. When I click on it in Design Mode it is identified as `=EMBED("Forms.ToggleButton.1","")`. And (with the tab open) when I click on View Code, the VBE goes to the the correct sheet and I can see ToggleButton1 is coded correctly:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
Range("AU6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("AU7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
Range("AU18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "UP"
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16738048
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf ToggleButton1.Value = False Then
Range("AU6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
Range("AU7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
Range("AU18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DN"
With Selection.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
End Sub
```

It worked before. I have tried right and left click and I have made sure Design Mode is not on. The only thing I am not sure about is whether the tabsheet and toggle were initially created in another workbook and copied over to the workbook I am now working with.

I'm sure this has to be something simple, but I'm a bit of a novice on the backside of Excel. Hope somebody can help. Many thanks, Jan

Comment: When you click the toggle button what happens? Nothing? Does it show an error in the VBA code?

Comment: Exactly, Alex. Absolutely nothing happens. No VBA code error is flagged, so I guess the button on the sheet is simply not getting to/linked with the code.

Comment: And you have enabled macros, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have the `name` of the toggle button incorrect in your code (this could happen if copied from one sheet to another).

1. Open `design mode` and double click the toggle button to enter `VBE`
2. Press `F4` to open the `Properties` pane
3. Check the `(name)` field (usually at the top)

The name should match *exactly* to `ToggleButton1` in your code e.g. if `name` is `ToggleButton2` then in your code you need `ToggleButton2`.

The identifier `=EMBED("Forms.ToggleButton.1","")` on the worksheet is irrelevant.

Finally, you can tidy up your code if you like as follows:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    Range("AU6").FormulaR1C1 = IIf(ToggleButton1, "2", "5")
    Range("AU7").FormulaR1C1 = IIf(ToggleButton1, "3", "6")
    Range("AU18").FormulaR1C1 = IIf(ToggleButton1, "UP", "DN")
    Range("AU18").Font.Color = IIf(ToggleButton1, -16738048, -16776961)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the improved code. I tried your suggestion, but no luck.

Comment: I double click on the button, and get to Properties. In the right hand frame I see the code. The Properties frame below left is headed Properties - Sheet20 and has two fields named Name, (Name) set to Sheet20, and Name set to TimePortStarboard. This seems right as I renamed Sheet20 to TimePortStarboard.  I also have some macros on the sheet (work fine). When I go to the code stored in a module renamed update and then go to Properties the frame that comes up is headed Properties - update. I.e., I do not get info about the actual macro(s) in the module, same as about the Button on Sheet20.

Comment: I closed Excel, reopened a new book and tried to insert a new toggle on a blank page, by clicking and then outlining a rectangle on a sheet in the usual way. When I release the pointer I get an Error Message: Cannot Insert Object. Again this is a new experience. What has changed? Anybody any idea?

Comment: This is a bug caused by a recent microsoft update. Go [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036) to fix it.